# Deal with accented character in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, rest, tomcat, mapreduce, non-ascii-characters

I've been struggling to find an ideal way to deal with accented characters.

First i use this two methods to encode(decode) text before inserting(fetching) in mongo.

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(unescape(s));
}
```

This method works fine when i fetch comments from mongodb and display them (ajax request) :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http:www.mywebsite.com/comments",
    type : "get",
    data : "key=" + env.key + "&login=" + login,
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(response) { console.log(decode_utf8(reponse.texte)); /* yay works fine */ },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
});
```

But when i use the code (map function of MapReduce) below it's doesn't handle accent:

```
String map = "function map() { "
                 + "var texte = decodeURIComponent(unescape(this.comment));"
                 + "var words = texte.match(/\\w+/g);" 

                 + "if(words) "
                 +     for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) 
                 +         emit(words[i].toLowerCase(), 1);" 
             + "}"
```

Ex: Instead of `ùùdzedzed` the result is `dzedzed`.
Any suggestion or workaround would be great.

EDIT :

My mongo content :

{ "_id" : ObjectId("55460441e4b00700737c56cc"), "id" : "c0ab4be5-f4f3-4c73-a7a0-f6863b6ce6511430651969105", "auteur_login" : "testlogin", "auteur_id" : 1, "comment" : "Ãªtre oÃ¹ rÃ¨glem Ã§a", "date" : "Sun May 03 13:19:29 CEST 2015" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("554612f1e4b0953aca0c0be0"), "id" : "aaa52859-5de6-469b-a17f-aa4615db77f71430655729171", "auteur_login" : "testlogin", "auteur_id" : 1, "comment" : "Ã  la", "date" : "Sun May 03 14:22:09 CEST 2015" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("55461c21e4b0643ea96f7933"), "id" : "ba3ae7c0-39a6-4c77-86ec-d193e39759b71430658081921", "auteur_login" : "testlogin", "auteur_id" : 1, "comment" : "voilÃ ", "date" : "Sun May 03 15:01:21 CEST 2015" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5547f5ede4b055c2ffb1a592"), "id" : "a9a1e7d4-c28d-4f9e-98d5-3fe7fba3bb5e1430779373121", "auteur_login" : "testlogin", "auteur_id" : 1, "comment" : "vb vb vb", "date" : "Tue May 05 00:42:53 CEST 2015" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5547f5fbe4b055c2ffb1a593"), "id" : "b5ad2b7e-987f-4d32-b5ca-bc06bdc57f611430779387478", "auteur_login" : "testlogin", "auteur_id" : 1, "comment" : "vb vb", "date" : "Tue May 05 00:43:07 CEST 2015" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5548b88ee4b029bc67d7a638"), "id" : "451e4e0d-c15a-4657-82c3-7760555b6c811430829198040", "auteur_login" : "testlogin", "auteur_id" : 1, "comment" : "ecrit n'importe quoi", "date" : "Tue May 05 14:33:18 CEST 2015" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("554b9409e4b004c1b252f9cb"), "id" : "f36c3b49-72b1-48f4-ae92-a7933bc1e2761431016457515", "auteur_login" : "moi12345", "auteur_id" : 9, "comment" : "salut", "date" : "Thu May 07 18:34:17 CEST 2015" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("554b941be4b004c1b252f9cd"), "id" : "1adc6788-32be-4c3a-bd73-16dad0b4bb741431016475777", "auteur_login" : "moi12345", "auteur_id" : 9, "comment" : "regregerhg", "date" : "Thu May 07 18:34:35 CEST 2015" }

And this is the result :

"sfsdfs": 58.0 update

"ta": 58.0 update

"test1": 58.0 update

"teste": 9.666666666666666 update

"ton": 58.0 update

"tre": 29.0 insert

"try": 58.0 update

"tudiant": 58.0 insert

"tweed": 58.0 update

"une": 58.0 update

"va": 19.333333333333332 update

"vb": 29.0 update

"veux": 19.333333333333332 update

"vient": 58.0 update

"voil": 58.0 insert

Example: the last line i should be getting `voilà`instead of `voil`

Comment: What is the problem that you're trying to solve with the encoding and decoding?

Comment: By encoding/decoding i'm trying to handle accented characters correctly. When i insert `ùdzedzed` i got this `ã¹dzedzed`

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything like that in your map function. MongoDB uses UTF-8 and can store accented characters just fine. A more complete example showing sample data and your full map-reduce would be helpful.

Comment: Can you replace your images with the actual text? That would let people copy the docs and reproduce the problem locally.

Comment: I replaced the images.

Comment: I looks like you're not storing your strings properly as they should show correctly in the docs. Also, please use code formatting and proper indenting for your JSON to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

So, essentially, your "encode_utf8" method does a weird way of converting UTF-8 string into 8-bit bytes. Why are you doing that?

([de/en]codeURIComponent() uses UTF-8 encoding, [un]encode uses ISO-8859-1)

For symmetry, your "decode_utf8(s)" shall be

```
return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
```

instead of "unescape".

Note that escape() and unescape() Javascript methods are deprecated

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as i mentionned i didn't find a workaround or something to replace it with.